# Livewire Updated hook with multiple input

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

I have this data

```
$date = '21-10-1996';
$id = '1';
$count = 0;
```

And now I want to update the **$count** data when every **$date** data and **$id** data are updated in the livewire form.

> how to properly do that?

I have done

```
public function updateddate($selected_date){
    return($selected_date);
}
public function updatedid($selected_id){
    $count = select:where('id', $selected_id)->where('date', $this->updateddate($this->date)->count);
}
```

but the data will only be updated if I change the **$id** only.
if I change the **$date**, I have to update the **$id** after that so that the **$count** data is updated.

Comment: but this is going to be achieved on form submit ?

Comment: @Prospero yes I will save it when I submit, if I update the time to the $date and $id data the data will be saved during the update but if I update the $date again, the data will be the same as before until I update the $id data

Answer (score 0):

the updated hook is camelcase, so in your cases must be:

```
public $id,$dates,$count = 0;

public function udpatedId($value) {}

// or

public function updatedDates($value) {}
```

If your function must resolve the logic after form submit, you can do it without the updated hook. Otherwise, you only need to do it on updatedId hook

```
public function updatedId($value)
{
   if($value) {
      $this->count = User::where('id',$value)->where('date',$this->date)->count();
   }   
}
```